# Micronaut unit tests not detecting beans from another package

Tags: java, maven, micronaut

I'm picking up an application in my organization that hasn't been maintained recently, so it's still on Micronaut 2.0.0. It's on our list to upgrade, but we need to produce some new functionality first. Initially, the project was a single package, with a single pom.xml that inherits from the micronaut parent pom. We need to add a worker to this repository that must share code with the service, so I have split the code up.

Right now the structure is as follows

```
.
├── libs
│   └── common
│       └── pom.xml
├── apps
│   ├── service
│   │   └── pom.xml
│   ├── worker
│   │   └── pom.xml
│   └── pom.xml
└── pom.xml
```

Each pom.xml lists the pom.xmls in its immediate subdirectories as modules. libs/common/pom.xml is a project that provides common types and some beans that need to be used by apps/service/pom.xml and eventually by apps/worker/pom.xml

`./apps/service/pom.xml` lists `./libs/common/pom.xml` as a dependency for both the common's jar and test-jar

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xxx</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xxx</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The service also configures the micronaut-maven-plugin from io.micronaut.build as follows. Without the dependencies and configuration sections below, the application will start from `mn:run` but will not detect any controller beans

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <watches>
            <watch>
              <directory>apps/service/src/main/resources</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
              </includes>
            </watch>
            <watch>
              <directory>apps/service/src/main</directory>
            </watch>
          </watches>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

With this, I am able to `mvn mn:run --projects apps/service` and have a working application. The service is able to pick up all of the beans and instantiate them.

However, I am running into a problem with tests. When I run `mvn test` , the tests on the `common` project pass, but the ones on `server` fail with a runtime error indicating that the tests from server cannot locate beans defined in `src/main` of the `common` package.

```
>[ERROR] xxx.api.controller.AssetControllerTest.getAllBuildingsForAssetNullEmptySpacesTridTest(String)[3] -- Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< ERROR!
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: 
Failed to inject value for field [companyRepository] of class: xxx.api.controller.AssetControllerTest
....
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [xxx.common.domain.repository.impl.CompanyRepository] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2284)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1233)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForField(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1465)
        ... 114 more
```

I have the annotation processors configured as instructed, in both the service and common pom.xmls (not sure if both is necessary, honestly)

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${project.lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=xxx</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=yyy/arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <annotationProcessorPaths>
                <path>
                  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.lombok.version}</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                </path>
                <path>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                  <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                </path>
              </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

What is generally supposed to be true in order to have unit tests with micronaut pick up poms from dependencies?